# Filter array by included prefix

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I've got the following array :

```
[David, Daniel, Dude, Dwayne]
```

How do I get a list of the names that starts with "Da"? The output should be :

```
[David, Daniel]
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `.filter()` as -

```
["David", "Daniel", "Dude", "Dwayne"].filter((element)=> element.startsWith('Da'))
```

Outputs

```
Array [ "David", "Daniel" ]
```

The filter function is applied on an array. Inside this, we are just checking if the element starts with `Da`, if that condition returns false, the function will filter that element out.

More array methods you can find [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)